# Converting shapefile to digraph

Tags: python, shapefile, network, nodes, networkx

I have used '''nx.read_shp''' for converting shapefile to network, but the result I am getting is quite different from how the actual shapefile looked like.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What did you expect? It is simply the plot of a Networkx DiGraph with [circular_layout](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout.html)

Comment: I thought the graph would be of the same shape as that of the shapefile, is the circular one fine to find out the centrality measures?

Comment: This is not a geospatial problem. The layout of the networkx plot determines only the graphical position of the nodes and does not affect the [centrality measures of the Digraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/centrality.html)